# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance with use effect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Not to sure why, but I am getting this error message:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```

Is there a way to map over data to be able to store in the `useEffect` before the `useEffect` is triggered?

As it looks like this map does not seem to work.

```
  const projectId = scheduleData && scheduleData.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
const schedules = () => {


  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)


  const [scheduleData ,setScheduleData] = useState(null)
  const [usageMode, setUsageMode] = useState(false)

  const [scheduleFieldData, setScheduleFieldData] = useState({})

  const [projectsAutoComplete, setProjectsAutoComplete] = useState([])
  const [domainsAutoComplete, setDomainsAutoComplete] = useState([])

  console.log(projectId, 'projectId');

  console.log(projectsAutoComplete)

  const projectId = scheduleData && scheduleData.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))

useEffect(() => {
  setProjectsAutoComplete([...projectId])
}, [])
  console.log(projectsAutoComplete);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadScheduleData(){
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const results = await get('get_testing_schedules', user.user)
      setScheduleData(results.data)
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }
    onLoadScheduleData()
  },[])

  const onClick = () => {
    setUsageMode(!usageMode)
  }

  console.log(usageMode);

  const onScheduleFieldUpdate = (e, valueFromAutoComplete, nameFromAutoComplete) => {

    const name = nameFromAutoComplete ? nameFromAutoComplete
    : e.target.name || e.target.getAttribute('name')
    const value = valueFromAutoComplete ? valueFromAutoComplete.map(val => val.value).join(',')
      : e.target.innerText ? e.target.innerText
      : e.target.value

      setScheduleFieldData({...scheduleFieldData, ...{[name]: value}})
  }

  const onDomainAutoCompleteFieldUpdate = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.innerText.toLowerCase()
    const projectIdFiltered = projectId.filter(id => id.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(value))
    setProjectsAutoComplete(projectIdFiltered)
  }
  console.log(scheduleFieldData);

  return (
    <div className=' CriticalObjectsGrid'>
 
       <React.Fragment>
          {configs.map((config, k) => {
            const Field = config.field
            return (
              <div key={k} className='Main' style={{textAlign: 'center'}} >
                <Field  
                  uniqueIdentifier={k} 
                  name={config.name} 
                  onChange={onScheduleFieldUpdate}
                  onSelect={onScheduleFieldUpdate}
                  onAutoCompleteOnChange={onDomainAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
                  value={scheduleFieldData[config.name]}
                  initialValues={
                  scheduleFieldData[config.name]}
                  options={projectsAutoComplete}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </React.Fragment>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default schedules
```

Updated code

```
const schedules = () => {


  const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
  const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
  const user = useContext(UserContext)
  const autoComplete = useContext(AutoCompleteContext)



  const [scheduleData ,setScheduleData] = useState(null)
  const [usageMode, setUsageMode] = useState(false)

  const [scheduleFieldData, setScheduleFieldData] = useState({})

  const [projectsAutoComplete, setProjectsAutoComplete] = useState([])




  // const projectId = scheduleData && scheduleData.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))



  const [ScheduleAutoComplete, setScheduleAutoComplete] = useState([])


  const intervals = ['"Daily"', '"Weekly"']

  const projectId = scheduleData && scheduleData.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))

useEffect(() => {
  // setProjectsAutoComplete([...projectId])

  setScheduleAutoComplete([...intervals])




}, [])

console.log(projectsAutoComplete);




  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadScheduleData(){
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const results = await get('get_testing_schedules', user.user)
      setScheduleData(results.data)

      if (projectId){setProjectsAutoComplete([...projectId])
      }
      loading.setLoading(false)
    }
    onLoadScheduleData()
  },[])

  const onClick = () => {
    setUsageMode(!usageMode)
  }

  console.log(projectsAutoComplete);



  const onScheduleFieldUpdate = (e, valueFromAutoComplete, nameFromAutoComplete) => {

    const name = nameFromAutoComplete ? nameFromAutoComplete
    : e.target.name || e.target.getAttribute('name')
    const value = valueFromAutoComplete ? valueFromAutoComplete.map(val => val.value).join(',')
      : e.target.innerText ? e.target.innerText
      : e.target.value

      setScheduleFieldData({...scheduleFieldData, ...{[name]: value}})


  }

  const onDomainAutoCompleteFieldUpdate = () => { 
    setScheduleAutoComplete(intervals)
    setProjectsAutoComplete(projectId)



  }

  console.log(projectsAutoComplete);



  return (
    <div className=' CriticalObjectsGrid'>
      {usageMode === false ? 
        <React.Fragment>
          <Button
          text='Creat schedule'
          onClick={onClick}
          />
        </React.Fragment>

        :

        <React.Fragment>
          {configs.map((config, k) => {
            const Field = config.field
            return (
              <div key={k} className='Main' style={{textAlign: 'center'}} >
                <Field  
                  uniqueIdentifier={k} 
                  name={config.name} 
                  onChange={onScheduleFieldUpdate}
                  onSelect={onScheduleFieldUpdate}
                  onAutoCompleteOnChange={onDomainAutoCompleteFieldUpdate}
                  value={scheduleFieldData[config.name]}
                  initialValues={scheduleFieldData[config.name]}
                  options={config.name === 'interval' ? ScheduleAutoComplete : config.name === 'project' ? ['projectsAutoComplete'] : []  }

                />
              </div>
            )
          })}


        </React.Fragment>
      }


    </div>
  )
}

export default schedules
```

Comment: can you print out scheduleData ? [...projectId]: projectId doesn't seem to be an array (non-iterable)

Comment: Yeah sure it returns me an array [70,71] I have updated in my code

Comment: It looks like when I hit the use effect it does not want to pick it up

Comment: Try  
`const projectId = scheduleData ? scheduleData.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x})) : []`
It needs to always be an array even if there is no scheduleData

Comment: Hey, thanks but when I log projectsAutocomplete it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

This error is referring to your attempt to spread `projectId` in your first `useEffect` hook. At the time of execution, `projectId` has a value of null, since it's getting it's value from the following line where `scheduleData` has an initial value of null.

```
const projectId = scheduleData && scheduleData.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
```

To avoid this error you could simply wrap `setProjectsAutoComplete([...projectId])` in an `if (projectId)` check like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (projectId){
      setProjectsAutoComplete([...projectId])
   }
}, [])
```

but a better solution would be to combine your two `useEffect` hooks, so that `setProjectsAutoComplete([...projectId])` is run after `onLoadScheduleData()`

EDIT:

Try this:

```
    const [projectId, setProjectId] = useState([])

    const intervals = ['"Daily"', '"Weekly"']

    async function onLoadScheduleData(){
        loading.setLoading(true)
        const results = await get('get_testing_schedules', user.user)
        if (results.data) {
            id = results.data.map(item => item.project_id).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
            setProjectId(id)
            setProjectsAutoComplete([...id])
        }
        loading.setLoading(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setScheduleAutoComplete([...intervals])
        onLoadScheduleData()
    },[])

    const onClick = () => {
        setUsageMode(!usageMode)
    }
```

I've removed the `scheduleData` variable entirely as it doesn't look like it needs to be kept in state. Instead I've made `projectId` a stateful variable, as it does seem to be used elsewhere. I moved the `onScheduleLoadData` function definition to outside of the useEffect hook and moved the `projectId` logic inside of it. I've also combined both useEffect hooks because they had the same dependencies. Let me know if this is more what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks, but I get returned an emptyy array, any ideas?  I'll update the code

Comment: I'll edit my solution with some new code for you